# Exclude special characters in the start and end of the string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want a regular expression to exclude special characters in the start and end of the string

I tried this code but its not working

```
String strFileName = Regex.Replace(FileName, @"[^A-Za-z0-9-_ ]", "");

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID = "Regular" 
            ValidationGroup = "valGroup" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "txtreport"
            ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid data."
            ValidationExpression = "([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Define "special". Also, I want a pony.

Comment: If you are doing something like validating web input, you should usually *include* the characters you want rather than *excluding* the ones you don't want.  That way if you make a mistake, it doesn't create an exploitable bug in your program.

Comment: @Jake 
strFileName = Regex.Replace(FileName, @"[^A-Za-z0-9-_ ]", "");


<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Regular" 
                ValidationGroup="valGroup" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtreport" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid data."
                ValidationExpression="([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: Can you edit the question and add that code to the question?  This will increase your odds of someone seeing it and helping :)

Comment: `A-Za-z0-9_` could be shorthanded to `\w`, i.e. `[^\w -]` should be enough for your example.

Comment: @kirilloid I want exclude Special Character only in start and end of the string.What can i do...?

Comment: @kirilloid: Careful: In .NET regexes, `\w` matches a lot more than `[A-Za-z0-9_]` since it's Unicode-aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there, just add anchors to tie the match to the start or end of the string, and tell the regex engine to match more than just one character:

```
String strFileName = Regex.Replace(FileName, 
    @"^              # Match the start of the string
    [^A-Z0-9_ -]+    # followed by one or more characters except these
    |                # or
    [^A-Z0-9_ -]+    # Match one or more characters except these
    $                # followed by the end of the string", 
    "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Also, your `ValidationExpression` is strange.

```
ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

would mean the same, but doesn't allow `_`, `<space>` and `-` which your "special character replacer" is ignoring. So you might want to use

```
ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*"
```

Comment: Thanks . Its working

But I want exclude Special Character  only in start and end of the string.

Comment: @Sachin: Right, of course. Well, then you don't need a ValidationExpression any more, do you?

Comment: What exactly *is*  your problem? You haven't defined that clearly. Do you want to do a replace operation on the user's input, or do you want to do a validation of the user's input?

Comment: If any user type special character in start and end of the text box. I want to display message "Invalid Data"(Only in start and end of the text box)

Comment: @Sachin: Then use the regex I proposed for the replace operation as the ValidationExpression instead (`^[^A-Za-z0-9_ -]+|[^A-Za-z0-9_ -]+$`)